# How to generate an Image from ImageData in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, putimagedata

I would like to know if there is any way to create a new Image from ImageData, which was previously obtained from a canvas element.

I've searched for a solution, but they all seem to be drawing the result to a canvas.

I need a way to convert an ImageData object to an Image directly, if it's possible.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf

Comment: great! exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use **toDataURL** method in Canvas.
It makes a image data as Data URI.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 100;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

If you want to know user's browser supports Data URI Scheme, You can use this function.

```
function useSafeDataURI(success, fail) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    img.onerror = function () {
        fail();
    };
    img.onload = function () {
        success();
    };

    img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="; // insert a dot image contains 1px.
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but doesn't the question ask the opposite? how to get an image from a ImageData object?

Answer (score 74):

None of the previous answers provide an answer to the question as it was presented in the subject - getting an Image from ImageData. So here's a solution.

```
function imagedata_to_image(imagedata) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = imagedata.width;
    canvas.height = imagedata.height;
    ctx.putImageData(imagedata, 0, 0);

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Although it's not unambiguous, I think the asker was looking for answers not involving drawing to a canvas as part of the process.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming this is your canvas

```
<canvas id='mycanvas'></canvas>
```

You can get a representation of your image using

```
var imgData = document.getElementById('mycanvas').toDataURL();
```

You could then put that in a regular image tag by changing its source

```
<img id='myimage'/>

document.getElementById('myimage').src = imgData;
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot  of modern browsers support Data URI scheme.

If you have the image data, you can set the src attribute of an img element using JavaScript.

Look at the following example:
http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/

Comment: In order to set the src of an image you need to convert the ImageData to a data URL. So it is confusing to write that if you have the "image data" you can set the src attribute. If you mean "ImageData", it is wrong and if you mean "data URL" it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Image class is in fact HTMLImageElement, creating it from ImageData is cumbersome. Depending on application, I would propose to look at more abstract thing CanvasImageSource, for which HTMLImageElement aka Image() is implementation. For example, ImageBitmap may be created right from data, yet OffscreenCanvas could be a useful thing.