# HTML5 Canvas linear image animation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm new to Canvas and I've started using an example of a simple linear motion animation from [HTML Canvas Tutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-linear-motion-animation/).

Is it possible to replace the rectangle so it displays an image instead?

Every time I've attempted editing the code the image that's outputted is static so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                            function(callback) {
                                                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                                        };
                                    })();

                                    function drawRectangle(myRectangle, context) {
                                        context.beginPath();
                                        context.rect(myRectangle.x, myRectangle.y, myRectangle.width, myRectangle.height);
                                        context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
                                        context.fill();
                                        context.lineWidth = myRectangle.borderWidth;
                                        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
                                        context.stroke();
                                        context.drawImage = 'images/player.png';
                                    }

                                    function animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime) {
                                        // update
                                        var time = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;

                                        var linearSpeed = 200;
                                        // pixels / second
                                        var newX = linearSpeed * time / 1000;

                                        if (newX < canvas.height - myRectangle.height - myRectangle.borderWidth / 2) {
                                            myRectangle.y = newX;
                                        }

                                        // clear
                                        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                                        drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

                                        // request new frame
                                        requestAnimFrame(function() {
                                            animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
                                        });
                                    }
                                    var canvas = document.getElementById('monopoly-piece');
                                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                                    var img = new Image;

                                    var myRectangle = {
                                        x: 20,
                                        y: 0,
                                        width: 50,
                                        height: 50,
                                        borderWidth: 5,
                                        img: 'images/player.png'
                                    };

                                    drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

                                     // wait one second before starting animation
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                                        animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
                                    }, 1000);
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: this might help: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Comment: Thanks for the response @snies I'm aware of the drawImage method but as a complete novice of Canvas I'm not entirely sure how to implement it into the existing code...

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here you go, a working example at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zymz2dLo/61/

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

// get canvas and create drawing context
// this assumes there is some canvas with id 'myCanvas'
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// create image
var img = document.createElement("img");

// fill image from data string
//img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="; // insert a dot image contains 1px

// or fill image from url
img.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg"


// define the linear speeds
var xSpeed = 0.05;  //px per ms
var ySpeed = 0.01;

// this function will animate the next 'frame' 
// based on input from the last 
function animate(nowTime, lastTime, xPos, yPos) {
    if ((img.style.width + xPos) > canvas.width) {
        xPos = 0;
        yPos = 0;
    }

    // calculate the delta in order to match the speed 
    var timeDelta = nowTime - lastTime;
    var xDelta = xSpeed * timeDelta;
    var yDelta = ySpeed * timeDelta;

    // clear
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //draw img
    context.drawImage(img, xPos, yPos);

    //schedule animation for the next available frame
    requestAnimationFrame(
        //wrap animate in a anonymous function to 
        //match the callback signature 
        function(timestamp){
            animate(timestamp, nowTime, xPos + xDelta, yPos + yDelta);
        }
    );
}

animate(0, 0,  10, 1);
```

additional info can be found here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

[How to generate an Image from imageData in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416800/how-to-generate-an-image-from-imagedata-in-javascript)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

**EDIT :**
 The above example updates as fast as possible, to scale it down a bit wrap the call to `requestAnimationFrame` in a `setTimeout` call.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot @snies . One small thing which is that I need the image to stop animating once it hits the edge of the canvas like the rectangle does in the tutorial. Is this to do with the requestAnimationFrame function?

Comment: yup, you would have to guard the execution of requestAnimationFrame with some stop condition like `if (xPos < canvas.width)` or something like that. And of course than you don't need the rest to zero part.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @snies . I managed to get the effect I was looking for with the following code. Could probably do with a bit of tidying up but it works for now

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

                                    var canvas = document.getElementById('monopoly-piece');
                                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                                    var img = document.createElement("img");
                                    img.src = "images/player.png"

                                    var xSpeed = 0;  //px per ms
                                    var ySpeed = 0.1;

                                    function animate(nowTime, lastTime, xPos, yPos) {
                                        // update
                                        if ((img.style.height + yPos) > canvas.height) {
                                            xPos = 0;
                                            yPos = 0;
                                        }
                                        var timeDelta = nowTime - lastTime;
                                        var xDelta = xSpeed * timeDelta;
                                        var yDelta = ySpeed * timeDelta;

                                        // clear
                                        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                                        //draw img
                                        context.drawImage(img, xPos, yPos);

                                        if (yPos > canvas.height - img.height ) {

                                        }
                                        else {
                                            requestAnimationFrame(
                                                    function(timestamp){
                                                        animate(timestamp, nowTime, xPos + xDelta, yPos + yDelta);
                                                    }
                                                );
                                            }

                                    }

                                animate(0, 0, 20, 1);
```