# How to convert ImageData into .png/.jpeg image and showing it on img HTML tag in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with a project in which I process the uploaded image from img HTML tag. As a result of processing, I am getting ImageData. Now, what I want to do is to convert ImageData into .png or .jpeg image and show that changed image in img tag. I tried "imagedata_to_image()" function in this page.

[How to generate an Image from ImageData in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416800/how-to-generate-an-image-from-imagedata-in-javascript)

However, I am getting white page with img removed.

```
 const iimage = imagedata_to_image(dataNew);
 document.getElementById("pic").src = iimage;
```

Any solution?

Comment: The answer you linked to describes it correctly, if that doesn't work it has to do with how you get the image data. How are you even getting `ImageData` from a file upload? They tend to either be an `ArrayBuffer`, `string` or `Blob` type, not `ImageData`, but since that code isn't here we can't help with that part.

Comment: If you *look* at the `imagedata_to_image` function in the provided link, you'll see that it returns an `Image`, *not* something you would add to `.src =`.   Maybe try `document.getElementById("pic").src = iimage.src;`

Comment: @somethinghere I am getting ImageData because I am processing the image. Then I wanted to convert it into image again to show the processed image. However, I debugged and I am getting null from the answer I linked. Do I need to wait for processing?

Comment: Please update your question to include a *complete* snippet that demonstrates the issue; otherwise we're just guessing what you *might* have done in the code you've not provided.   The snipp will ned to include the function from the linked answer as well how you create `newData` along with any relevant HTML (such as `<img id='pic'>`.   The snippet needs *demonstrate* the issue.

Comment: Again, this is ver hard to debug if we can't see any of the code that is generating your `ImageData`. Whether the operations are async, or if you missed some return statement or the like. If what you have is _actual valid `ImageData`_, the answer you linked should work (given that you use `.src`).

Comment: @somethinghere Is it necessary to create "canvas", if I want to create an image from ImageData?

Comment: If you *don't* want to use the previous, linked answer then state that in your question.  That answer uses canvas.  If you question is simply "how do I do this" then we'd close as a duplicate of the one you've linked to, so you'd need to be clear that (for whatever nefarious reason) you don't want to use that answer and don't want a canvas.  Please be specific in your requirements, *within* the question.

Comment: Yes, as the only way to _create_ `ImageData` objects is through canvas, so the only way to turn them into images is canvas. Why do people want to avoid canvas so much? It's just a programmer tool like any other function and it's waaaay faster than computing a dataURL manually.

Comment: @somethinghere, Yes the operation is async but I am getting ImageData. I checked.

Comment: There's no `async` in the question.   Please update the question details.

Comment: Are you getting `Promise<ImageData>` or `ImageData`? Also, _inspect_ your image data. If all the data is `0` you simply _have no valid data_. If the `width` or `height` isn't defined, you have no data. It's very well possible that somewhere in the chain your imagedata got corrupted and the output breaks, there's no way for us to know _without knowing your process or code_

Comment: Actually, I am using async in callback function for image processing. I cannot show my image processing code. However, in "imagedata_to_image", I am not using async.

Comment: I am not using Promise<ImageData> or ImageData?.

Comment: We have added enough comments, please add _more context_ to the code above, try to give us all the information to debug with, as much of it as you can muster. If it's a library that's processing, then tell us that. Give us more code, as clearly, there isn't enough here to help and we will vote to close this question due to the need for clarification.

Comment: Then provide a mock of the data, ie `var dataNew = ....` we just need to see the code not working, not a half-snippet out of context.